# Network is not connected - spatstat package in R

Tags: spatstat

I am learning spatstat in R. As a first step I am converting my shapefile to be suitable for spatstat algorithms. When I use `as.linnet` to converted to linear network (the last line in the code below), I get a warning `network not connected`

```
roads<-readShapeSpatial("OnlyHigwayroads.shp")
spatstat.roads<-as.psp(roads)
final_roads<-as.linnet(spatstat.roads)
Warning message:
Network is not connected
```

I do not understand what it means. I took the shapefile back into arcgis and queried for dangles and there was not report of dangles. I also randomly checked few intersections, but I did not find any breaks in the connections.

So what does spatstat mean by network is not connected?

Thanks.

Comment: It could be very hard to guess what the problem is without access to the data. Can you provide a link to the data?

Comment: How can I do that? Is there something like a private message in this forum? The example I am following is here [this link(http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/rds/NLD_rds.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a warning, not an error.

A road network is connected if it is possible to drive between any two points on the network using only those roads.

If your network consists of several highways (to the exclusion of other types of roads) and there are two highways in your network which are joined only by a minor road, then the highway network is not connected.